# How to select a burst frequency of an Ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, sensors, embedded-systems, signal-processing

I am  using an Ultrasonic sensor to detect obstacles for adas applications. Is there a way to find the optimal burst frequency? experimentally or theoretically? for object detection.

How does changing the burst frequency affect the obstacle detection capabilities of ultrasonic sensor?

Comment: how often to burst or what frequency the burst should be?

Comment: My question was pertaining to frequency of the burst. But the first option didn't strike me as well. Would appreciate if you could help me with both.